# How does C++ multiple inheritance virtual function access derived class field?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

Referencing the [multiple inheritance memory layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921372/c-virtual-table-layout-of-mimultiple-inheritance), suppose `Derived` class has a field called `int derived_only`. If I have a `Base1 * b1` and `Base2 * b2`, both pointing to the same `Derived` class object, then according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table#Multiple_inheritance_and_thunks), `b1` and `b2` have slightly different values due to pointer fixup. My question is, if I call a virtual function, say the `virtual clone()`, by using either `b1` or `b2`, how does `clone()` calculate `derived_only`'s address, from either `b1` or `b2`?

Basically, when calling `b1->clone()` vs `b2->clone()`, the `this` pointer passed in is different, then how does `clone()` know how much offset to add to `this` to get to `derived_only`?

Comment: because it's a virtual function?

Comment: if you can get `derived*` from `base*`, I don't think compiler has any hard do that cast itself.

Comment: What you have written could be explained with a code snippet, which is much easier to read and make sense than raw explanation

Comment: `b1` points at the `Base1` sub-object of `Derived`. As long as `Base1` isn't a virtual base, it will always be in the same position in `Derived`. The compiler knows where it is, and the call to `clone()` will adjust the pointer as needed.

Comment: The "how" is inconsequential per the standard. The language only dictates that it works :-) You'll have to track down actual implementations to see what they do. You could, for example, initialize a set of function pointers upon creation of derived class object. Calling through the base class simply uses those same function pointers that have already been set up to call the appropriate function.